# Create RSS Feed from Xml

Tags: xml, json, rss

I want to track newly upcoming events from a website. But there's no easy way to subscribe to event updates from website interface, so I used rest api to get results in json or xml format.

Website allows to have only limited number of requests. I want to create an RSS feed to see newly upcoming events ( using api I can sort results by date events were added ) and because of limitation update the file e.g. every Monday.

Is there a way how I can do it ( I know only Java )? Where I can start?

Answer (score 0):

There are many potential ways to do this.   One way to start would be to use the [Rome RSS library](http://freecode.com/projects/rome-rss) in java.  Pull the JSON from the site on some regular interval, then translate the JSON into RSS (this would be a combination of your code, with Rome handling RSS generation).   Then just save that RSS locally, and serve it on demand.

The trouble is that if the website you're pulling from only requires a certain number of requests per day, your RSS feed can't update more often than that.  So essentially you would be serving up a static RSS file at all times, with a background process that updates the RSS file on predictable intervals.

You should check with the content provider about whether or not they'd permit that though.  It's highly likely they wouldn't want you doing that.